# what is swingset2

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I looked at some demos but did not find any articles that explain the concept.

[Demo link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjava.sun.com%2Fproducts%2Fjfc%2Fjws%2FSwingSet2.jnlp&ei=Y-xWSsOSD5T7tgex6PndCg&usg=AFQjCNGWki9C_BLV5fUkYdxhFyB0-zmXxg&sig2=9olvfcuWLHu8t-fQ46Lb3A)

Comment: Could you link those demos in your question?

Answer (score 6):

Swingset is a java demonstration of the swing feature in java which is a set of cross platform gui options.  It was made to showcase swing.   Its somewhat useful in that you can see the code of the gui with the swingset.

Comment: It is also very useful to test different Look and Feels or a new LAF development.

Answer (score -2):

SwingSet are some free libraries for improve some elements from Swing. Fro example it has a Grid which you can connect to a ResultSet and Combos etc.

Comment: hmm ... what exactly you are refering to?